# Datatype-generic programming libraries for Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, generic-programming

I'm looking for a Scala library allowing for datatype-generic programming (like [Scrap Your Boilerplate](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/hmap/), for example). A list of libraries with appropriate links and short descriptions for each one would be a perfect answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well,

- [Adrian Moors](http://people.cs.kuleuven.be/~adriaan.moors) has reimplemented [Jeremy Gibbons](http://www.comlab.ox.ac.uk/jeremy.gibbons/)' [Origami](http://www.comlab.ox.ac.uk/jeremy.gibbons/publications/origami.pdf) [programming](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.60.5251) : [The paper](http://www.comlab.ox.ac.uk/jeremy.gibbons/publications/origami.pdf). [The source](http://people.cs.kuleuven.be/~adriaan.moors/wgp2006/).
- [Bruno Oliveira](http://ropas.snu.ac.kr/~bruno/) and Jeremy Gibbons have re-implemented [Hinze](http://www.comlab.ox.ac.uk/ralf.hinze/)'s *[Generics for the masses](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=459213)*,   [Lämmel](http://www.uni-koblenz.de/~laemmel) & [Peyton-Jones](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/simonpj/)' *[Scrap your Boilerplate with Class](http://homepages.cwi.nl/~ralf/syb3/)*, and *Origami Programming*, and written [a detailed comparison about it](http://ropas.snu.ac.kr/~bruno/papers/ScalaGeneric.pdf).
  Source [here](http://www.comlab.ox.ac.uk/projects/gip/Scala.tgz).
- Naturally, the [Scala Collections library](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/2060) itself can easily be seen as an instance of generic programming, [as Martin Odersky explains](http://drops.dagstuhl.de/volltexte/2009/2338/pdf/09005.OderskyM.2338.pdf), if only because of its reliance on implicits, Scala's flavor of [Type Classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_classes).

Answer (score 4):

Christian Hofer, Klaus Ostermann, Tillmann Rendel and Adriaan Moors's [Polymorphic Embedding of DSLs](http://www.daimi.au.dk/~ko/papers/gpce50_hofer.pdf) has some  [accompanying code](http://www.daimi.au.dk/~rendel/dsl/) which is 'very generic'.  They cite [Finally Tagless, Partially Evaluated](http://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~ccshan/tagless/jfp.pdf) as an 'important influence', which endears this paper to me for some reason...