# What is the easiest way to update an immutable AST?

Tags: scala, macros, abstract-syntax-tree, scala-2.10

While working with macros, I have reached the point (I have been trying hard to avoid it) where I need to update those nodes in the AST which hold certain condition. For instance, let's say I would like to update each node:

```
Literal(Constant(1))
```

with the value:

```
Literal(Constant(2))
```

Those AST nodes could be anywhere in the expression tree, so I cannot use an ad-hoc pattern matcher. Obviously, the last thing I would like to do is to code a full pattern matcher which is able to cover all the compiler primitives. I have been searching in the [API](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/milestone/index.html#scala.reflect.api.Trees%24TreeApi) but I have the impression that methods such as *collect* and the *traversable* family are not good enough to fulfill my needs, since they treat the tree as a linear thing, and I want the whole updated tree as a result. So, is it possible to update an immutable expression tree in a smart way? Why doesn't exist such 'update' operation in the standard API?

Comment: For plugins there is a TreeTransformer. I suppose there must be a similar for macros, perhaps even the same.

Comment: Probably you will want to check out [zippers](http://anti-xml.org/zippers.html)

Comment: @NikitaVolkov, i'd say that if he wasn't asking in the context of macros.

Comment: What I talked about http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/compiler/index.html#scala.tools.nsc.transform.Transform - but it seems to be for plugins only.

Comment: Transformers seem really interesting. I'm going to look for its possible application in macros. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of using an AST transformer in a Scala macro:

https://github.com/retronym/macrocosm/blob/171be7e/src/main/scala/com/github/retronym/macrocosm/Macrocosm.scala#L129

Comment: I really have to look up the source code for Transformer. It looks like the XML transform library, and that library has exponential performance on the depth of the tree.

Comment: A wild shot at the issue: does this relate to top-down vs bottom-up traversal? In a top-down traversal, changing a leaf implies rebuilding the tree above.
The implementation of `traceImpl`, in the link above, suggests that new trees are constructed bottom-up (at least there). But, in general, it depends on how you call `super.transform`.

Answer (score 2):

Modifying poly-typed nodes in data structures generically is a classic case of datatype generics (parameterization of code via type constructor).

Several approaches exist for such operations, such as the ["Scrap Your Boilerplate"](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Research_papers/Generics) approach, which define datatype generic traversal functions.

In Haskell, the node update function is parameterized in two dimensions: by datatype and by code -- so you can apply different update functions to different types, anywhere in a structure:

```
-- | Apply a transformation everywhere in bottom-up manner
everywhere :: (forall a. Data a => a -> a)
           -> (forall a. Data a => a -> a)
```

Doing so in Haskell relies heavily on type classes. In Scala, there are several [ported examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3031449/83805)