# Applying type constructors to generated type parameters with Scala macros

Tags: scala, reflection, macros, type-constructor, materialize

I am trying to materialize an instance of the (simplified) trait

```
trait TC[F[_]] {
  def apply[A](fa: F[A]): F[A]
}
```

using Scala macros. The signature of the macro therefore is

```
def materialize[F[_]](c: Context)(
  implicit fT: c.WeakTypeTag[F[_]]): c.Expr[TC[F]]
```

Type constructor `F[_]` now needs to be applied to the type parameter `A` for two reasons:

1. To write the signature of `apply` above for a particular `F` (like `Foo[A]`)
2. To inspect the members of the type `Foo[A]` in order to specify an interesting body of `apply`

Is there any way to create the type corresponding to the method type parameter `A` that can than be used in `appliedType`? It appears difficult for me, since the method `apply` and its type parameter `A` are also just being generated as trees.

---

I tried to take `WeakTypeTag[TC[F]]` as additional argument to the macro call and received the paramter type by

```
val paramT = wfg.tpe.member("apply": TermName).tpe.typeParams.head.tpe
```

but then using `paramT` in `q"... def apply[$paramT] ..."` does result in

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't splice "A" as type parameter
```

so this appears also to be no solution.

Comment: Are you using scala 2.10?

Comment: Also, speaking of `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't splice "A" as type parameter`, could you share the full code?

Comment: Hey Eugene, I have been using 2.10, but switching between 2.10 and 2.11.2 did not make any difference as far as I noticed. The full (finally working) code now [lives here](https://github.com/b-studios/MixinComposition/blob/master/macros/src/main/scala/Composition.scala)

Comment: Have you tried `appliedType`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing the definition of the above trait to

```
trait TC[F[_]] {
  type ApplyF[A] = F[A]
  def apply[A](fa: ApplyF[A]): ApplyF[A]
}
```

and **typechecking the tree for a dummy value**:

```
typecheck(q"""new TC[Foo] {
  def apply[A](fa: ApplyF[A]): ApplyF[A] = ???
}""").tpe
```

The typechecked result then could be destructed and transformed (by means of [tree transformers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397900/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-update-an-immutable-ast)) to fill in the `???`. This did not solve the problem completely, yielding the type error:

```
found   : A(in method apply)(in method apply)(in method apply)...
required: A(in method apply)(in method apply)(in method apply)...
```

While calling `untypecheck` before returning the tree did not help - inspection of the resulting tree however showed that the expected result is valid (type correct) Scala code. Thus, the last step that made the macro finally fly was to call

```
parse(showCode(result))
```

It feels completely unnecessary, but it seems that this was the only way to get rid of conflicting type information.